# how to save IP address of raspberry pi to a text file

Tags: networking

I would like to know if there is any script in either python or C, by which I can save the IP address of my raspberry pi to a text file every time it boots up. I need to send this IP address to another raspberry pi who's IP address is static. I application that I am designing prevents me from assigning a static IP to the ther raspberry pi's. I plan to use socket program to send the IP address between the PIs.

I am also open to other methods of doing this if there are any!
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is possibly technically off-topic but no different to dozens of others which ask how to find IP address of Pi - except it explains why he wants to do it and how he propses to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple shell script to grab `eth0`'s IP address.

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}' > /home/pi/ip.txt
```

For an example, I will save this as `ip.sh` in my home directory: `/home/pi/ip.sh`

Make sure to mark it executable with:

```
chmod +x /home/pi/ip.sh
```

Then to run this script at start up, open up `/etc/rc.local` and make it look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
sh /home/pi/ip.sh &
exit 0
```

Comment: Seems a bit unnecessary to run `grep`, `cut` and `awk` when `awk` can do the lot on its own... `ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet /{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the address for most protocols. See the "Connecting a Computer to the Pi" section in [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

`RemotePi=$(getent hosts hostname.local | awk '{ print $1 }')` should give you the remote IP address. (The Pi should have unique `hostname`.)